# How can I rewrite URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to convert this URL:

```
mysite.com/cgi-bin/test.cgi/some_random_numbers_and_letters/http/www.somewebsite.com
```

into:

```
mysite.com/www.somewebsite.com
```

I also want to convert this URL:

```
mysite.com/addname.php
```

into:

```
mysite.com/add/
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.bloghash.com/2006/12/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/) and you will learn how to use `mod_rewrite` and practice yourself.

Comment: Good answer. I learnt everything I know (not very much, admittedly, but enough for this question) from http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Within .htaccess or apache2.conf

```
Rewrite Engine On
Rewrite Rule ^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z]+)\.(.{1-5})$ cgi-bin/test.cgi/letters/http/$1$2$3
Rewrite Rule ^addname.php$ cgi-bin/addname.cgi
Rewrite Rule ^add/?$ cgi-bin/addname.cgi
```

EDIT:

```
Rewrite Engine On
Rewrite Rule ^add/(.*)$ cgi-bin/addname.cgi$1
Rewrite Rule ^addname.php(\?(.*))$ cgi-bin/addname.cgi$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
Rewrite Rule ^((.*)\.)?(.*)(\.[A-Za-z\.]{2,8})(/.*)$ cgi-bin/test.cgi/?subdomain=$1&urlname=$2&tld=$3&path=$4 [L]
```

Fixed and actually tested the regex this time.
The $1, $2,$3,$4 match the parts of the domain.
The whole domain can be specified simply by using $1$2$3$4
I used a domain regex so only domains will be matched, and other website paths would not.

Comment: it may not always be www. it coudl be any subdomain.